# Textbox Should be generated if i specify number of textbox in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose i have one text box in html that will specify number of textbox should be generated dynamically with sequence of textbox id using html and javascript.
how to do that?

Comment: I literally have no idea what this means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using java script and it would be easy if you use jquery.

if your code is

```
<input type=text id=noOfTb onchange="change();"/>
<div id=tbs>
</div>
```

then add jQuery and following script

```
<script type=javascript>
function change(){
var no= $("#noOfTb").val();
for(var i=0;i<no;i++){
    $("#tbs").append("<input type=text id="+i+" >");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you please give me the javascript code becuase i am facing problem executing with jquery..

Comment: I am writing only script here thinking same one input and div.
`<script type=javascript>
function change(){
var no = document.getElementById("noOfTb");
var inputTags = "";
for(var i=0;i<no;i++){
 inputTags += "<input type=text id="+i+" >";
}
document.getElementById("noOfTb").innerHtml(inputTags);
</script>`

Comment: Please do let me if problem persist

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this:

```
$("input.number").on("change", function() {
    var num = $(this).val();
    for(var i=0; i<num; i++) {
        $(this).after('<input type="text" />');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/9c5jY/